# Xamarin forms zxing ZXingScannerView on ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, barcode, zxing

I am writing a mobile app in xamarin forms and I have half the screen continuously scanning barcodes using ZXingScannerView. This works great in android however in ios it will not pick up any barcodes using ZXingScannerView. However ios does pick up barcodes using the full page ZXingScannerPage. In my example code below the method Scanner_OnScanResult is never getting hit. How can I get this to work in ios am i missing something?

```
ZXingScannerView scanner = new ZXingScannerView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
            IsScanning = true,
            Options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
            UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = false,//update later to come from settings
            PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>(),
            TryHarder = true
            }
        };

        ZXingDefaultOverlay overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay();

 scanner.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);.

 scanner.OnScanResult += Scanner_OnScanResult;

 private void Scanner_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Exit", "TEST", "Yes", "No");
        }
```

Comment: i think that is a bug, after trying a few combination of barcode scanning https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got this working however i'm not sure if its a bug or just inconsistent design but in iOS IsAnalyzing must be set to true manually when working in a view